# SQL - Selecting rows with a specific column value in the row after it

Tags: sql, presto

I am looking at selecting columns only if they have a specific value in the row immediately following it.

Using the example of the following data frame:

```
Date           ID             Symbol
2020-06-05     C              AAPL
2020-06-05     U              AAPL 
2020-06-06     R              AAPL
```

I want to code it so I only return the second row I since it is followed by an 'R' in the 'ID' row

At the moment I am using the following code structure to check values beforehand. I am wondering if something similar could be altered to potentially work for this as well.

```
select t.* from table t
where not exists (
  select 1 from table
  where id < t.id and val > t.val)
```

Thanks

Comment: Your example has two "first rows" and one "third row". There's no "second row" there. Rows do not have inherent ordering, unless you specify an ordering criteria.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  "Followed by 'R'" applies to two rows, not one.

Answer (score 0):

You have ties in the data.  Let me assume that the date really has a time component, so this is not an issue.

In that case, you can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lead(id) over (partition by symbol order by date) as next_id
      from t
     ) t
where next_id = 'R';
```